# Retrieve a number from a webpage

Tags: html, python-3.x

I'm trying to modify the tutorial from this page:

https://python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/scrape.html

and to extract only the version number of the software, number that it is changing daily. The number for today is: 741641f4c3b8

https://builder.blender.org/download/

Unfortunately I can't manage to work.

This is my modification:

```
# https://python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/scrape.html
#pip install lxml
#pip install requests

from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://builder.blender.org/download/(index)')
tree = (index).fromstring(page.content)

#This will create version number:
version = tree.xpath('//span[@class="name"]/text()')

# <span class="name">2.80 Beta Windows 64 bit<small>June 18, 00:46:53 - 741641f4c3b8</small></span>
```

I just starting learning Python so still I don't know how to adapt this code to my needs.

Please help.

Comment: you can try using beautifulsoup and html5lib as a parser instead. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-web-scraping-python-beautiful-soup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Beautifulsoup. The code below works fine but outputs an unnecessary 'small' text, hope that's not a problem.

```
#remember to pip install bs4 and requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


source = requests.get("https://builder.blender.org/download/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content,("lxml"))

a= soup.find("span",{'class':'name'})
print(a.find('small'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both answers. The @SergeHauri solution seems better as the output is exactly the number that I need.

Comment: Ok, I managed to download the daily buid as .zip file using the python script. Now the only issue remaining is to properly unzip this file as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645077/unzip-all-files-and-directories-from-a-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of your code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://builder.blender.org/download/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create version number:
version_text = tree.xpath('//li[@class="os windows"]/a[@ga_label="Dev Windows 64 bit master"]/span[@class="name"]/small/text()')
version = version_text[0].split(" ")[-1]
print(version)
```

I don't know what you wanted with `(index)` - the `fromstring` method is part of the imported html package.

With xpath you can select the dom node you want, i.e. the text within the `<small>` node within `<span class="name">` within `<a ga_label="Dev Windows 64 bit master">` within `<a class="os windows">`. (The Search feature in chrome DevTools - Elements can search by xpath, which is very handy to test your xpath expression)

This returns a list of all found results, but since we know there's only one, we can just access it with `version_text[0]`.

Then, since the version number is only part of the text, we can access it with `.split(" ")[-1]`, which splits the text on all spaces and selects the last element, which should be the version number.

---

The xpath expression you provided just selects the text content in `<span class="name">` (i.e. "2.80 Beta Windows 64 bit"). to select the text containing the version number, you should select the text of the `<small>`-node, `//span[@class="name"]/small/text()`. Using this xpath expression in the code above finds 10 results, but since the one you're looking for is the first one, it would also work correctly.